# c++ Decrypting msg from game client

Tags: c++

i made a socket that accepting connection from a game , in the game u should type in username and password , i can recive it bt , it's like ummmm encrypted letteers and numbers(”VeDbç)
3¥ثuo_‰°"“Fِمض)

my question is where to look at so i can understand how to deal with this prob , is there a tut. or hint or somthing that i can work on so i can reach what am looking for!?

thanks.

---

```
unsigned char* Key3;
unsigned char* Key4;
unsigned char Low;
unsigned char High;

const unsigned char Key1[] = 
{
    0x9D, 0x90, 0x83, 0x8A, 0xD1, 0x8C, 0xE7, 0xF6, 0x25, 0x28, 0xEB, 0x82, 0x99, 0x64, 0x8F, 0x2E,
    0x2D, 0x40, 0xD3, 0xFA, 0xE1, 0xBC, 0xB7, 0xE6, 0xB5, 0xD8, 0x3B, 0xF2, 0xA9, 0x94, 0x5F, 0x1E, 
    0xBD, 0xF0, 0x23, 0x6A, 0xF1, 0xEC, 0x87, 0xD6, 0x45, 0x88, 0x8B, 0x62, 0xB9, 0xC4, 0x2F, 0x0E, 
    0x4D, 0xA0, 0x73, 0xDA, 0x01, 0x1C, 0x57, 0xC6, 0xD5, 0x38, 0xDB, 0xD2, 0xC9, 0xF4, 0xFF, 0xFE, 
    0xDD, 0x50, 0xC3, 0x4A, 0x11, 0x4C, 0x27, 0xB6, 0x65, 0xE8, 0x2B, 0x42, 0xD9, 0x24, 0xCF, 0xEE, 
    0x6D, 0x00, 0x13, 0xBA, 0x21, 0x7C, 0xF7, 0xA6, 0xF5, 0x98, 0x7B, 0xB2, 0xE9, 0x54, 0x9F, 0xDE, 
    0xFD, 0xB0, 0x63, 0x2A, 0x31, 0xAC, 0xC7, 0x96, 0x85, 0x48, 0xCB, 0x22, 0xF9, 0x84, 0x6F, 0xCE, 
    0x8D, 0x60, 0xB3, 0x9A, 0x41, 0xDC, 0x97, 0x86, 0x15, 0xF8, 0x1B, 0x92, 0x09, 0xB4, 0x3F, 0xBE, 
    0x1D, 0x10, 0x03, 0x0A, 0x51, 0x0C, 0x67, 0x76, 0xA5, 0xA8, 0x6B, 0x02, 0x19, 0xE4, 0x0F, 0xAE, 
    0xAD, 0xC0, 0x53, 0x7A, 0x61, 0x3C, 0x37, 0x66, 0x35, 0x58, 0xBB, 0x72, 0x29, 0x14, 0xDF, 0x9E, 
    0x3D, 0x70, 0xA3, 0xEA, 0x71, 0x6C, 0x07, 0x56, 0xC5, 0x08, 0x0B, 0xE2, 0x39, 0x44, 0xAF, 0x8E, 
    0xCD, 0x20, 0xF3, 0x5A, 0x81, 0x9C, 0xD7, 0x46, 0x55, 0xB8, 0x5B, 0x52, 0x49, 0x74, 0x7F, 0x7E, 
    0x5D, 0xD0, 0x43, 0xCA, 0x91, 0xCC, 0xA7, 0x36, 0xE5, 0x68, 0xAB, 0xC2, 0x59, 0xA4, 0x4F, 0x6E, 
    0xED, 0x80, 0x93, 0x3A, 0xA1, 0xFC, 0x77, 0x26, 0x75, 0x18, 0xFB, 0x32, 0x69, 0xD4, 0x1F, 0x5E, 
    0x7D, 0x30, 0xE3, 0xAA, 0xB1, 0x2C, 0x47, 0x16, 0x05, 0xC8, 0x4B, 0xA2, 0x79, 0x04, 0xEF, 0x4E, 
    0x0D, 0xE0, 0x33, 0x1A, 0xC1, 0x5C, 0x17, 0x06, 0x95, 0x78, 0x9B, 0x12, 0x89, 0x34, 0xBF, 0x3E
};
const unsigned char Key2[] =
{
    0x62, 0x4F, 0xE8, 0x15, 0xDE, 0xEB, 0x04, 0x91, 0x1A, 0xC7, 0xE0, 0x4D, 0x16, 0xE3, 0x7C, 0x49,
    0xD2, 0x3F, 0xD8, 0x85, 0x4E, 0xDB, 0xF4, 0x01, 0x8A, 0xB7, 0xD0, 0xBD, 0x86, 0xD3, 0x6C, 0xB9,
    0x42, 0x2F, 0xC8, 0xF5, 0xBE, 0xCB, 0xE4, 0x71, 0xFA, 0xA7, 0xC0, 0x2D, 0xF6, 0xC3, 0x5C, 0x29,
    0xB2, 0x1F, 0xB8, 0x65, 0x2E, 0xBB, 0xD4, 0xE1, 0x6A, 0x97, 0xB0, 0x9D, 0x66, 0xB3, 0x4C, 0x99,
    0x22, 0x0F, 0xA8, 0xD5, 0x9E, 0xAB, 0xC4, 0x51, 0xDA, 0x87, 0xA0, 0x0D, 0xD6, 0xA3, 0x3C, 0x09,
    0x92, 0xFF, 0x98, 0x45, 0x0E, 0x9B, 0xB4, 0xC1, 0x4A, 0x77, 0x90, 0x7D, 0x46, 0x93, 0x2C, 0x79,
    0x02, 0xEF, 0x88, 0xB5, 0x7E, 0x8B, 0xA4, 0x31, 0xBA, 0x67, 0x80, 0xED, 0xB6, 0x83, 0x1C, 0xE9,
    0x72, 0xDF, 0x78, 0x25, 0xEE, 0x7B, 0x94, 0xA1, 0x2A, 0x57, 0x70, 0x5D, 0x26, 0x73, 0x0C, 0x59,
    0xE2, 0xCF, 0x68, 0x95, 0x5E, 0x6B, 0x84, 0x11, 0x9A, 0x47, 0x60, 0xCD, 0x96, 0x63, 0xFC, 0xC9,
    0x52, 0xBF, 0x58, 0x05, 0xCE, 0x5B, 0x74, 0x81, 0x0A, 0x37, 0x50, 0x3D, 0x06, 0x53, 0xEC, 0x39,
    0xC2, 0xAF, 0x48, 0x75, 0x3E, 0x4B, 0x64, 0xF1, 0x7A, 0x27, 0x40, 0xAD, 0x76, 0x43, 0xDC, 0xA9,
    0x32, 0x9F, 0x38, 0xE5, 0xAE, 0x3B, 0x54, 0x61, 0xEA, 0x17, 0x30, 0x1D, 0xE6, 0x33, 0xCC, 0x19,
    0xA2, 0x8F, 0x28, 0x55, 0x1E, 0x2B, 0x44, 0xD1, 0x5A, 0x07, 0x20, 0x8D, 0x56, 0x23, 0xBC, 0x89,
    0x12, 0x7F, 0x18, 0xC5, 0x8E, 0x1B, 0x34, 0x41, 0xCA, 0xF7, 0x10, 0xFD, 0xC6, 0x13, 0xAC, 0xF9,
    0x82, 0x6F, 0x08, 0x35, 0xFE, 0x0B, 0x24, 0xB1, 0x3A, 0xE7, 0x00, 0x6D, 0x36, 0x03, 0x9C, 0x69,
    0xF2, 0x5F, 0xF8, 0xA5, 0x6E, 0xFB, 0x14, 0x21, 0xAA, 0xD7, 0xF0, 0xDD, 0xA6, 0xF3, 0x8C, 0xD9
};

// Decrypt Function
void CAuthCryptography::Decrypt(void* in, void* out, int Length)
{
    unsigned char* pIn = (unsigned char*)in;
    unsigned char* pOut = (unsigned char*)out;
    for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
    {
        pOut[i] = (unsigned char)(pIn[i] ^ 0xAB);
        pOut[i] = (unsigned char)((pOut[i] << 4) | (pOut[i] >> 4));
        if (UsingAlternate)
        {
            pOut[i] = (unsigned char)(Key4[In.High] ^ pOut[i]);
            pOut[i] = (unsigned char)(Key3[In.Low] ^ pOut[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            pOut[i] = (unsigned char)(Key2[In.High] ^ pOut[i]);
            pOut[i] = (unsigned char)(Key1[In.Low] ^ pOut[i]);
        }
        In.Counter++;
     }
}
```

i got this code and it's working but can someone explain to me how it's working becuase i dont understand it?!
or if there is a tut. i can read or something

Comment: Try googling: reverse engineering network protocols.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use something like WireShark, tcpdump etc to view the TCP stream, just to make sure you haven't bodged up your tcp data-reading code.  More generally, if you are getting data like that, then only the sending side will know why, and you either ask them or look at how that data is handled by some other receiving program they've made (i.e. debug another client, find out what it does with that mess).

Answer (score 1):

When it really is encrypted, your chances are low.

But chances are it's just UTF-7 or UTF-8 encoded, not encrypted.
And if it is SSL on a non-standard port, use [oSpy](https://github.com/oleavr/ospy/releases).